# Django database error while connecting sqllite

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

```
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line      
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you read the error message: "ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details."? Did you do that?

Comment: Please read the last line, it contains instructions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to make migrations.